# Find $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{-x(\ln(1+y^2)+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{-x(\ln(1+y^2)+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$

I have tried approaching different paths to show that maybe it does not exist but I am really stuck.. appreciate any help!

P.S I have plugged this into wolfram alpha and it said that limit does not exist

Comment: Which paths did you try?

Comment: When I set $x=0$ i get limit is $0$, same for $y$. Also $y=x$ I also get 0 as a result, and for $y=mx$ the value of constant m does not matter i still get 0

Comment: Actually, if you set $y=x$, then what you get is $\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: It follows from the fact that$$f(x,x)=-\frac{x^2+\log \left(x^2+1\right)}{2 \sqrt{2} x^2}$$and that, near $0$, $\log(x^2+1)\approx x^2$. (BTW, the limit is $-\frac1{\sqrt2}$.)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=mx$

Then you get $$\frac{x(\ln(1+m^{2}x^{2})+m^{2}x^{2})}{x^{2}(1+m^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{x\ln(1+m^{2}x^{2})+m^{2}x^{3}}{(1+m^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}x^{3}}$$

Now use the fact that $\displaystyle\frac{x\ln(1+m^{2}x^{2})}{x^{3}}=\frac{\ln(1+m^{2}x^{2})}{x^{2}}\xrightarrow{x\to 0} m^{2}$ to see that

for $y=mx$ the limit equals $\displaystyle\frac{-2m^{2}}{(1+m^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ which is different for different $m$.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, polar coordinates reveal clearly the non-existence of the limit.
As usual $x=r\cos t,\; y=r\sin t$:
\begin{eqnarray*} -\frac{x(\ln (1+y^2) + y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac 32}}
& = & -\frac{\cos t}{r^2}\left(\ln (1+r^2\sin^2 t) + r^2\sin^2 t\right) \\
& \stackrel{\sin t \neq 0}{=} & -\cos t \sin^2 t \left(\underbrace{\frac{\ln (1+r^2\sin^2 t)}{r^2\sin^2 t}}_{\stackrel{r\to 0}{\longrightarrow}1} + 1\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
So, obviously the behavior of the expression for $r \to 0$ depends only on $t$ and different values like $t= \frac{\pi}2$ or $t= \frac{\pi}4$ produce different results.